# HTML TextArea Fit Content (On Page Load)

Tags: html, css

I've got a text area that displays text pulled down from a database (of variable length) and I want the text area to resize, currently its appearing with a  fixed height (of about 2 text lines) and then scrolling the rest. What can I do to the CSS to make the text area shrink and grown based on the `$t4_data` size when the page loads?

I don't want it to dynamically resize with jQuery or anything, just when the page loads. No jQuery if possible.

The page is built using PHP:

```
echo "<textarea form='t4_area_post_form_" . $t4_id . "' name='message' id='t4_post_item_" . $t4_id . "' class='t4_payload' readonly>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($t4_data);
echo "</textarea>";
```

The CSS is:

```
.t4_payload {
text-align:left;
float:left;
word-wrap:break-word;
width:555px;
font-size:14px;
margin-top:10px;
resize:none;
display:inline-block;
border:none;
background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an inline style on your textarea, giving it a height calculated by the number of lines in $t4_data multiplied by the font-size. You'll have to change your font-size in your CSS to something in pixels rather than a percentage, too.

Comment: That sounds jQuery-ish, i've added the inline-block display and changed the text to 14px, still no change, is there anyway of doing this with native CSS?

Comment: you need to add to your textarea rows='" . numberOfRows($t4_data) . "' and define somewhere the function numberOfRows or simply calculate it from the length of $t4_data divided by the number of character in a row, rounded up to next integer.

Comment: Oo - ok i'll give that ago

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery. Remove the display:inline-block; and add an inline style i.e. style="height:<?php echo number_of_rows($t4_data) * 14; ?>px;". Your logic for number_of_rows depends on where you are getting $t4_data from

Comment: The $t4_data comes from a varchar field in a DB

Comment: function number_of_rows($str) {
 $lines_arr = preg_split('/\n|\r/',$str);
 return count($lines_arr); 
}